# Python CGI and Database End of script output before headers: register_insert.py

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to figure out why my html form, going into pythonCGI into a database is returning an error.
When I submit the form it says:

"
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: register_insert.py
"

Any help and advice would be appreciated!

This is my python code:

```
#! /Python/python

import dbfunc, mysql.connector, cgi, cgitb

cgitb.enable()  # to enable browser to show errors 
conn = dbfunc.getConnection()
cursor = ''

form = cgi.FieldStorage()               # receives all form data sent by client and saves in a dictionary (key, value pairs)

customer_info = {

customer_ID = 4
firstName = form.getvalue('firstName')  # get value of 'id' field sent by client form
lastName = form.getvalue('lastName')
addressLine1 = form.getvalue('addressLine1')
addressLine2 = form.getvalue('addressLine2')
city = form.getvalue('city')
county = form.getvalue('county')
postcode = form.getvalue('postcode')
phonenumber = form.getvalue('phonenumber')
email = form.getvalue('email')
password = form.getvalue('password')

}

print "Content-type: text/html \n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title> New Customer </title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"

if conn.is_connected():
  cursor = conn.cursor()

    new_register ("INSERT INTO registration "
                "(customer_ID, firstName, lastName, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, county, postcode, phonenumber, email, password) "
                "VALUES (%(customer_ID)d, %(firstName)s, %(lastName)s, %(addressLine1)s, %(addressLine2)s, %(city)s, %(county)s, %(postcode)s, %(phonenumber)s, %(email)s, %(password)s)")

    cursor.execute(new_register, customer_info)

    conn.commit()    
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

else:
    print ('<H2> Error in database connection </H2>')


print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

And HTML Form

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<table width = "400" border="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td> Test Form for booking <br /> <br /> 

<form action="register_insert.py" method="post">

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" >  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"> <br />

Address 1: <input type="text" name="addressLine1">  <br />

Address 2: <input type="text" name="addressLine2"> <br />

City: <input type="text" name="city">  <br />

County: <input type="text" name="county"> <br />

Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode">  <br />

Phone number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"> <br />

Email: <input type="text" name="email"> <br />

Password: <input type="text" name="password">  <br />


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</td>
</tr>
</table>















</BODY>
</HTML>
```